# How to show higher resolution image in mobile and lower resolution image in desktop?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I used some typical bootstrap grid for having a row of images with 4 images in desktop and 1 image in mobile. something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <img src="image1_src">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <img src="image2_src">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <img src="image3_src">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <img src="image4_src">
    </div>
</div>
```

Rendered size of image in browsers was about `250px*250px` but this resolution was not enough for mobile because images where almost fullscreen in mobile. I decided to use images with resolutions about `500px*500px` and image quality was very good in both version of mobile and desktop but it faced me with google pageSpeed warning that said:

> Image elements do not have explicit **width** and **height**

So I decided to use `<picture>` tag for using two different version of images. small one in desktop and big one in mobile!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width:701px)" srcset="250px_image1_src">
            <source media="(max-width:700px)" srcset="500px_image1_src">
            <img src="500px_image1_src">
        </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width:701px)" srcset="250px_image2_src">
            <source media="(max-width:700px)" srcset="500px_image2_src">
            <img src="500px_image2_src">
        </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width:701px)" srcset="250px_image3_src">
            <source media="(max-width:700px)" srcset="500px_image3_src">
            <img src="500px_image3_src">
        </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width:701px)" srcset="250px_image4_src">
            <source media="(max-width:700px)" srcset="500px_image4_src">
            <img src="500px_image4_src">
        </picture>
    </div>
</div>
```

now I'm facing with a new problem that browser pick image with higher resolution automatically in desktop mode and ignore the other one.

Comment: with resolution you mean clarity of the image or its just about size??

Comment: @KunalTanwar booth of them actually but main problem is about clarity. images with lower resolution have not enough clarity in mobile view.

Comment: use SVG's instead of PNG's!

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent issues going on here:

First: Google complaining about explicit width and height. If you provide the browser with width/height values, it provides the space needed in the layout, even if the image itself is not loaded yet. If there are no width/height values, the provided space will be zero until the image is loaded, causing a layout shift.

Second: You want to provide your images in different resolutions, because modern smartphones have a much higher screen resolution than common desktop monitors. By using the picture-tag, you tell the browser "these are the images I have, please decide which fits best into the current layout and resolution". Your last img-tag within your picture tag is the fallback option, which the browser will use if none of the media queries above fits. That's why it takes that picture.

See also https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Another way of implementing different resolutions would be using srcset. You find a very thorough explanation on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: thanks for your attention. your 'second' is something that I got in my last research steps and I'm using it in my code as you can see. but about your 'first:
unfortunately using width and height just solve google error but actually it's not the optimum way because I have to use image with higher resolution (500*500) but it's rendering in smaller size in desktop and I'm wasting resources of desktop viewers. because there is no tangible difference between 500*500 and 250*250 images in their view.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that enough. I try again: Your mobile viewers need a high-resolution version of your picture. Your desktop viewers don't. So you provide two different images. And now it is for the browser to decide what image it uses. The browser knows a) the screen resolution of the viewer's device and b) the actual space your image occupies in the current viewport. You don't. So it is up to the browser to decide. You find a very good explanation of how to provide different image versions in the second link in my answer :)

Comment: And don't worry too much about that "missing width/height" issue - in a responsive layout you normally just cannot know the current width/height of an image. So you may have to live with both the google "error" (it's not a real error) and the layout shift ...